# nltk corpus tweeter_sample by category

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I want to train the `nltk` with the `tweeter_sample` corpus, but I get an error when I try to load the sample by category.

First I tried like that:

```
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples

documents = [(list(twitter_samples.strings(fileid)), category)
             for category in twitter_samples.categories()
             for fileid in twitter_samples.fileids(category)]
```

but it gave me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/neptun/PycharmProjects/Thesis/First_sentimental.py", line 6, in <module>
    for category in twitter_samples.categories()
  File "C:\Users\neptun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 119, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'TwitterCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'categories'
```

I don't know how to give them the available attributes in order to have my list with positive and negative sentiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspect `twitter_samples.fileids()`, you'll see that there are separate positive and negative files:

```
>>> twitter_samples.fileids()
['negative_tweets.json', 'positive_tweets.json', 'tweets.20150430-223406.json']
```

So to get the tweets classified as positive or negative, just select the corresponding file. It's not the usual way the `nltk` handles categorized corpora, but there you have it.

```
documents = ([(t, "pos") for t in twitter_samples.strings("positive_tweets.json")] + 
             [(t, "neg") for t in twitter_samples.strings("negative_tweets.json")])
```

This will get you a dataset of 10000 tweets. The third file contains another 20000, which apparently are not categorized.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @alexis but I made a mistake in my question i want every words to be separate. Like that i will be able to use 'nltk.FreqDist(documents)'

Answer (score 0):

```
categorized_tweets = ([(t, "pos") for t in twitter_samples.strings("positive_tweets.json")] +
                            [(t, "neg") for t in twitter_samples.strings("negative_tweets.json")])


smilies = [':-)', ':)', ';)', ':o)', ':]', ':3', ':c)', ':>', '=]', '8)', '=)', ':}',
    ':^)', ':-D', ':D', '8-D', '8D', 'x-D', 'xD', 'X-D', 'XD', '=-D', '=D',
    '=-3', '=3', ':-))', ":'-)", ":')", ':*', ':^*', '>:P', ':-P', ':P', 'X-P',
    'x-p', 'xp', 'XP', ':-p', ':p', '=p', ':-b', ':b', '>:)', '>;)', '>:-)',
    '<3', ':L', ':-/', '>:/', ':S', '>:[', ':@', ':-(', ':[', ':-||', '=L', ':<',
    ':-[', ':-<', '=\\', '=/', '>:(', ':(', '>.<', ":'-(", ":'(", ':\\', ':-c',
    ':c', ':{', '>:\\', ';(', '(', ')', 'via']

categorized_tweets_tokens = []
for tweet in categorized_tweets:
    text = tweet[0]
    for smiley in smilies:
        text = re.sub(re.escape(smiley), '', text)
    categorized_tweets_tokens.append((word_tokenize(text), tweet[1]))
```